# how to solve this system of equations using gaussian?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, systems-of-equations

Please explain it step by step. I couldn't do it on my own. tried $3$ times, still got no solution to it. but it has infinitely many solutions.
$$ \begin{cases}2y+z+4v= -5\\
 2x-3y-z+2w+3v= 4\\
 4x-4y-z+4w+11v= 4\\
2x-5y-2z+2w-v= 9\end{cases}$$

Comment: which method do you use?

Comment: are you familiar with the matrices notation?

Comment: yeah but can you show it to me? @AlessioPellegrini

Comment: i used gaussian method @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: No, i just kinda learnt gaussian and gaussian Jordan plus the elementary row operations. @AlessioPellegrini